# Locking of flag requests, no marshal tag?

Tags: support

I have nominated myself to become a moderator. Within my 9 months of being registered (4-5 of being active), I have accrued 320+ flags and 360 edits (thanks to Spring Cleaning, [feel free to join in and help out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55978/spring-cleaning)). However, would my becoming a moderator lock me from getting Marshal for 500 flags since a moderator shouldn't be able to flag posts.

Comment: Well, you still can flag, but they won't be counted towards the badge.

Comment: So, I guess no marshal badge for me.. but being a moderator is a greater privilege and I am accepting this fact.. Unless.. ;P

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Won't they? You can still get "helpful flags" so I see no reason, why they wouldn't count.

Comment: In fact Loong was only one who went with me toe-to-toe in flags.

Comment: @Mithoron Because flags from moderators have immediate effects, thus they would always be helpful. I don't flag, because I don't have to. I can have the same effect with the direct actions. Occasionally I'm using flags, like spam, because it has desired effects for the system. Otherwise there really is no need for a moderator.

Comment: No, they don't count. I don't have the marshal badge.